# How do I fix my javascript Celsius converter?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
  "The temperature in Celcius is " + convertTemp() + "!"

function getInputValue() {
  var inputNumber = document.getElementById("numberEnter")
}

function convertTemp() {
  document.getElementById("result")
  return (5 / 9) * inputNumber - 32
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="What is the temperature..." id="numberEnter">
  <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Click to get temperature!</button>
  <p id="result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I make it so that the temperature actually appears and have the "The temperature in Celcius is  + convertTemp()" line actually appear when I run the code.

Comment: `inputNumber` is local to the function `getInputValue`. If you want the two functions to share state, the variable must be moved to the outer scope. The better option is to simply have `getInputValue` return the value, and then call that method from `convertTemp`.

Comment: Why do you have `document.getElementById("result")` in `convertTemp()`? It never does anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

You have to just add a Click Event listener to the button

```js
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `The temperature in Celsius is ${convertTemp(document.getElementById("numberEnter").value)} !`

function convertTemp(inputTemp) {
  return (5/9)*(inputTemp-32)
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `The temperature in Celsius is ${convertTemp(document.getElementById("numberEnter").value)} !`
})
```

```html
Fahrenheit: <input type="text" placeholder="What is the temperature..." id="numberEnter" value=0>
<button type="button" id="button">Click to get temperature!</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

And code without Event Listener (The shortest possible code i can make)

```js
function convertTemp() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `The temperature in Celsius is ${(5/9)*(document.getElementById("numberEnter").value-32)} °C!`
}
```

```html
°F: <input type="text" placeholder="What is the temperature..." id="numberEnter" value=0><button type="button" id="button" onclick="convertTemp()">Click to get temperature!</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

And tell me if its ok for you...

Answer (score 1):

`getInputValue()` should call `convertTemp()`, and then assign the result to `innerHTML`.

You need to use `.value` to get the input value.

In the formula, you have to put parentheses around `inputNumber - 32` to override the default operator precedence.

```js
function getInputValue() {
  var inputNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numberEnter").value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
    "The temperature in Celcius is " + convertTemp(inputNumber) + "!"
}

function convertTemp(inputNumber) {
  return (5 / 9) * (inputNumber - 32)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="What is the temperature..." id="numberEnter">
  <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Click to get temperature!</button>
  <p id="result"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without event listener:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" placeholder="What is the temperature..." id="numberEnter">
        <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Click to get temperature!</button>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <script>
           function getInputValue(){
            var inputNumber = document.getElementById("numberEnter").value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The temperature in Celcius is " + convertTemp(inputNumber) + "!"
           }
        function convertTemp(f){
            document.getElementById ("result")
            return (5/9) * (f - 32)
        }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Example:](http://tortoiseshell-silken-stranger.glitch.me/f2c.html)
https://tortoiseshell-silken-stranger.glitch.me/f2c.html